# How can I copy-paste an image into a form field on Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, images, copy-paste

I use a Google Pixel 6 with Android 12. I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

1. Copy the Android Enthusiasts site logo image
2. Navigate to the Ask Question page
3. Long-hold the form and select Paste

[image]

I have the same issue with the two other websites have tried, namely Gmail and GitHub.

How can I copy-paste an image into a form field on Chrome for Android without having to download and re-upload the image myself?

Comment: Use the image URL.

Comment: If the image is from a website, long press on the image, select Copy Image. Then go to the field you want the image to be pasted into, long-press on the field and select Paste.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks I've done but got some error as shown in the gif

Comment: @Robert  Thanks. I would like to copy the image instead of the URL in case that the website is private

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Apologies I opened Kiwi browser instead of Chrome.

Comment: I have tried a little experiment with copy-pasting images on Chrome for Android. Looks like SE Imgur uploader can accept JPG and PNG images fine, but not SVG (the site logo is in SVG format) and Gravatar image (API-returned image). However, I could copy-paste the SVG site logo to Google Keep fine. At this point, I'm afraid it's more of a problem with the SE Imgur uploader (which might be more suitable as a post on meta) rather than a general issue. Have you tried on other sites that also accept pasting images?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio  thank you. This is interesting to know that it works in the kiwi web browser

Comment: @AndrewT.  I have the same issue with the two other websites have tried, namely Gmail and GitHub

Comment: Do you still have the same issue? It seems to be working fine (at least on my side) with the latest version.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio nice, thank you. The issue is now fixed indeed. You are welcome to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in January 2022 when the OP asked the question, I had the same issue while pasting images with Chrome using the Paste option after using Copy image (but not with Kiwi browser, see comments).

With the latest Chrome version (98.0.4758.01), the issue has disappeared. Whatever the cause, it seems the Chrome developers have (for now) solved it.